# How to change the scene layout?

Tags: game-engine

I can change the scene and the layout of the object.

I want to know if Game Logic allows me to change the layout of the scene....
Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: imho "the layout of the scene" is an editor (blender program) setting, I doubt that game logic can operate on the editor settings...

Comment: @Júnior you can expand the explanation of what you want to do, edit your question and detail a little more, please